# Firestore Update Sub-Collection Document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to update a sub-collection document that I got by sending a **group-query** with Flutter. To my current understanding with a **group-query** I do not really know the parent of a sub-collection.

In order to do so, I need the document id of the parent document. The update query would then look like the following:

```
collection(collectionName)
.document(parentDocumentId)
 .collection(subCollectionName)
  .document(subCollectionDocumentId)
   .updateData(someMapWithData);
```

Is it necessary to save the parentDocumentId within the sub-collection document to be able to do such update or is there another way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update a document inside a subcollection, then you need both the top document id and the document id inside the subcollection.

> Is it necessary to save the parentDocumentId within the sub-collection document to be able to do such update or is there another way to do so?

No, its not necessary, but if you have the `parentDocumentId`, and you dont have the `subDocumentId`, then you need to query to retrieve it:

```
    Firestore.instance
        .collection("path")
        .document("docPath")
        .collection("subCollection")
        .where("name", isEqualTo: "john")
        .getDocuments()
        .then((res) {
      res.documents.forEach((result) {
        Firestore.instance
            .collection("path")
            .document("docPath")
            .collection("subCollection")
            .document(result.documentID)
            .updateData({"name": "martin"});
      });
    });
```

Comment: I get it. Although comparing it to your suggestion, saving the parentId within the document of the sub-collection would be less of a hustle also perhaps more cost-efficient?

Comment: In firestore you may have, collection -> document and inside the document you can have a subcollection that will contain multiple documents.. The multiple documents cannot have the same document id. So in the end, you are going to have to perform a query to be able to update the data. If you saved the parentId as a field (pID : parentId) in these multiple documents, then you will need to perform a query as in the example

Comment: In your query, you are doing a search, so when I have saved the parentId within the document of the subcollection this would not be necessary since I could do the following query: Firestore.instance.collection('path').document(**parentId**).collection('subCollection').document(documentId).updateData(...);

Comment: In my query I'm doing a search inside the subcollection, the parentid I already have it. But as I said each document must have a unique ID. Inside the subcollection you will have multiple documents with unique document id, in my query I'm searching for the document id inside the subcollection. How are you aiming to get this `document(documentid)`? If I'm understanding you correctly, you are saying that you will add the parentdocumentid as a document id for the child document. But again if you have multiple doc inside the subcollection they must have unique document id

Comment: Yes, this part where each document has its own id is clear to me. At this point, I have the id of the document found in the sub-collection. My question was concerning the search from bottom to top, to get the id of the parent document. So I think the best way is to just pass the parent's Id as a field to all of its "children".

Comment: Yes u can do that or you can use any other field that is inside the child document. You are updating data, let's say a user is updating his name, and you have a field called name then query on that, get the id and update

Comment: But in this case, I would have to do a search query first to update the document, which is not cost-efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find an option to do this more cost-efficient. With this method, you have 1 read and 1 write operation.

Code for the following storage structure: `users/${uid}/collection/$documentName/`

```js
static Future updateSubData(String uid, String mainCollection,
  String subCollection, Map<String, dynamic> json) async {
//get document ID
final querySnapshot = await fireStoreInstance
    .collection(mainCollection)
    .doc(uid)
    .collection(subCollection)
    .limit(1)
    .get();
//document at position 0
final documentId = querySnapshot.docs[0].id;
//update this document
await fireStoreInstance
    .collection(mainCollection)
    .doc(uid)
    .collection(subCollection)
    .doc(documentId)
    .update(json);
  }
```

I case you have more documents in the subcollection you need to remove `.limit(1)` so you get all documents.